# Get the same SHA-224 sum in Factor as coreutils sha224sum

Tags: glob, checksum, sha, factor-lang

```
$ echo *
a b c
$ cat *
file 1
file 2
file 3
$ factor -e=" \ 
> USING: globs io sequences sorting io.files io.encodings.utf8 ; \ 
> \"*\" glob natural-sort [ utf8 file-lines ] map concat [ print ] each "
file 1
file 2
file 3
```

The outputs are the same using Factor's glob and the shell's glob. A `diff` on the outputs shows they match exactly.

```
$ factor -e=" \
> USING: math.parser checksums checksums.sha globs io sequences sorting io.files io.encodings.utf8 ; \
> \"*\" glob natural-sort [ utf8 file-lines ] map concat sha-224 checksum-lines bytes>hex-string print "

0feaf7d5c46b802404760778091ed1312ba82d4206b9f93c35570a1a
$ cat * | sha224sum
d1240479399e5a37f8e62e2935a7ac4b9352e41d6274067b27a36101
```

But the checksums don't match, nor will `md5` checksums. Why is this? How do I get the same checksum in Factor as in coreutils `sha224sum`?

Changing the encoding to `ascii` doesn't change the output, nor does `"\n" join sha-224 checksum-bytes` instead of `checksum-lines`.

Comment: Aren't you missing a "\n" join anter concat? I think the factor code is hashing the array of the 3 file contents

Comment: nevermind, checksum-lines joins with ascii 10, so it's not that :/

Comment: Oh, it's the trailing newline that's missing! This was answered in the mailing list, would be nice to give an answer here too.

Comment: @fedes. Thanks for the heads up, and sorry to bother you c:

Comment: Don't worry, I'll bother you too when i need help! C:

Comment: @fedes. I'd appreciate your help in debugging a similar issue to this but on a scale too large for the mailing list or SO, it's really stumping me https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45210/conversation-between-cat-and-fede-s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This odd behaviour is due to a bug in checksum-lines. [factor/factor#1708](https://github.com/factor/factor/issues/1708)

Thanks to [jonenst](https://github.com/jonenst) for finding the problem, and [calsioro](https://github.com/calsioro) for this code on the Factor mailing list:

> This code:

> ```factor
> [
>     { "a" "b" "c" } 3 [1,b]
>     [ number>string "file " prepend [ write ] curry
>       ascii swap with-file-writer ] 2each
>
>     "*" glob natural-sort [ utf8 file-lines ] map concat
>     [ "\n" append ] map "" join  ! Add newlines between and at the end
>
>     sha-224 checksum-bytes bytes>hex-string print
> ] with-test-directory
> ```

> gives the same hash:

> d1240479399e5a37f8e62e2935a7ac4b9352e41d6274067b27a36101

Comment: (Actually it was John Harper who found the problem... credit should go to him, not me)

Comment: @fedes. Updated c:

Answer (score 0):

[jonenst](https://github.com/jonenst) also [pointed out](https://github.com/factor/factor/issues/1708#issuecomment-246174934) that:

> Also, regarding the three different lengths you get, "exercism/self-update/self-update.factor" is missing a '\n' char at the end of the last line. That's why you get surprising results.

If you're trying to checksum files, make sure they all end with a trailing newline.